# ImproperlyConfigured - Django

Tags: django

I am developping in Django.

But while I am trying to run my code, I got an `ImproperlyConfigured` error...

**Error:**

```
 ImproperlyConfigured at /acl/

PermissionGroupView is missing a QuerySet. Define PermissionGroupView.model, PermissionGroupView.queryset, or override PermissionGroupView.get_queryset().
```

**Views.py:**

```
class PermissionGroupView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'acl/acl-dashboard.html'
    success_url = '/acl/'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(PermissionGroupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            context['groups'] = GroupForm(self.request.POST)
            if context['groups'].is_valid():
                context['groups'].save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            context['groups'] = GroupForm()
            return context
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

**acl-dashboard.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Enter New Group</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form class="forms-sample" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ groups | crispy}}
                    <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

If someone knows how to help me!

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, you need to define either model or queryset. So change your view like this:

```
class PermissionGroupView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Group  # <-- Here, we defined the model. 
    template_name = 'acl/acl-dashboard.html'
    success_url = '/acl/'
```

For more details, please see [CreateView documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview).

**OR,** you can add `form_class` to your view, which will also attach the model name to `model` attribute of the view:

```
class PermissionGroupView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = GroupForm  # <-- Here, we defined the form. 
    template_name = 'acl/acl-dashboard.html'
    success_url = '/acl/'
```